# How to implement AuthorizeStep referer redirection?

Tags: aurelia

I've implemented the AuthorizeStep example code from the Aurelia doc (http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/8)

```
@inject(MdToastService,I18N)
class AuthorizeStep {
    constructor(toast:MdToastService,i18n:I18N) {
        this.toast = toast;
        this.i18n = i18n;
    }

    run(navigationInstruction, next) {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('subject')===null
            && navigationInstruction.config.settings!==undefined
            && navigationInstruction.config.settings.auth!==false) {
            this.toast.show(this.i18n.tr('backend:LOGIN_REQUIRED_DESCRIPTION'), 5000, 'error');
            return next.cancel(new Redirect('welcome'));
        }
        return next();
    }
}
```

If a user accesses the restricted area "/admin", he is getting redirected to "/welcome". But I want to remember the refererer "/admin", and redirect the user to this area after login.

```
return next.cancel(new Redirect('welcome',{referer:navigationInstruction.fragment}));
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had to ask the user for terms of use before I let them in. Terms of use was a different route and I had to remember where the user came from. I archived that with the following code.

The trick to inject a service class that can hold the state you need afterwards.

I wrote a service class TermsOfUseOptInService for handling the optin state, where user came from and the redirect route.
In the router pipeline step you can get information about the current route (fragment + queryString) from the navigationInstructions parameter and set them to the injected service class.

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { Redirect, NavigationInstruction, Next } from 'aurelia-router';
import { TermsOfUseOptInService } from '../resources/services/terms-of-use-opt-in-service'

@autoinject()
export class TermsOfUseOptInStep {

  constructor(private optInService: TermsOfUseOptInService) {

}
run(navigationInstructions: NavigationInstruction, next: Next): Promise<any>
{
  if (navigationInstructions.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.settings.thersOfUseOptIn)) {
    if (!this.optInService.TermsOfUseAccepted) {
      let backUrl = navigationInstructions.fragment;
      if (navigationInstructions.queryString) {
        backUrl += '?' + navigationInstructions.queryString;
      }
      this.optInService.backUrl = backUrl;
      let redirect = new Redirect(this.optInService.RedirectRoute);
      return next.cancel(redirect);
    }
  }
  if (!(navigationInstructions.config.name == this.optInService.RedirectRoute)) {
    this.optInService.backUrl = null;
  }
  return next();
  }
}
```

The view that handles the opt in also inject the TermsOfUseOptInService and can handle the back redirect.

```
if (this.optInService.backUrl) {
  this.router.navigate(this.optInService.backUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is not my preferred solution but I will give it a try ;)